# loading admin page after upgrading to django 3.0 crashes dev. server

Tags: django

I upgraded Django from 2.2 to 3.0, Now I can't access admin page.
Every time I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin the dev. server quits without any message or error.
If I revert back to Django 2.2 everything works fine.

I did fresh virtualenv and created new project unfortunately, I hit the same wall again the Dev. server quits without any error.

**Is this a common issue or do I have any error?**

I am using windows 10 64-bit and Pycharm community 2019.2.5

**my virtual is:**

```
Package             Version
------------------- ----------
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
idna==2.8
Pillow==6.2.1
pip==19.3.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
setuptools==42.0.2
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
twilio==6.34.0
urllib3==1.25.7
wheel==0.33.6
```

**Stack trace**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 06, 2019 - 21:59:45
Django version 3.0, using settings 'suhul_prj.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[06/Dec/2019 21:59:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16351
[06/Dec/2019 21:59:56] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[06/Dec/2019 21:59:56] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[06/Dec/2019 21:59:56] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[06/Dec/2019 21:59:56] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:02] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:02] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:02] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:03] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:03] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1233
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:03] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
[06/Dec/2019 22:00:08] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

(home_venv) C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\django_projects\suhul_prj>
```

Comment: Not a common issue. Without more information it's hard to tell what's the issue. How are you running your server? If you're on a linux/unix system, what do you see in the syslog? Have you tried restarting your system?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: You will need to add the stacktrace of your error. What's printing your console where the error happen or maybe the error that is being displayed in your browser

Comment: unfortunately it quits silently without any error. As if I used Ctrl+C .
I tried to make a fresh project with new env. and I get this error : sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

Comment: The last issue shows you haven’t done manage.py migrate.

Comment: I did the migrations and also created new superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like this problem going back to python and Django versions incompatibility, which caused WSGI segmentation fault, I had the same issue while I was using python 3.7 and with downgrading python to 3.6 it has been solved!

Comment: Thanks, I will check if this will solve my problem. Shouldn't it should work fine with 3.7?

Comment: already it works with python 3.7.5 fine, although it's a big bang bug that Django developers  didn't  find out

Comment: I checked it with 3.8 and it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my experience solving the same issue.

I used python v3.7 and got this issue. Solved this problem by upgrading to **python v3.8** and creating a new venv.

Now my python version FYI:
`Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224279/how-to-resolve-django-admin-error-with-302-problems/61607546#61607546) mentioned this issue.