# How to resolve django admin error with 302 problems?

Tags: django

I am continuously getting error while trying to log in to django admin page.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 07, 2019 - 13:53:40
Django version 3.0, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2027
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1233
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[07/Dec/2019 13:53:59] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

And after this it is automatically closing.

Comment: So what's the **error** here?

Answer (score 1):

I used python v3.7 and got this issue. Solved this problem by using **python v3.8** and creating a new venv.

Now my python version FYI:
`Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Answer (score 0):

302 is not an error.  It is a redirect.  When you try to visit `/admin/` you are redirected to the login page, and then when you have logged in you are redirected to `/admin/`.

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: @reza_khalafi , to resolve django admin error with 302 problems, must fix model and migrations. check fields default value, blank, null. (I think reply will help others)

Answer (score 0):

I set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in `settings.py` and works.