# Django server dies when try to connect /admin page

Tags: django, die

I'm trying to implement Restful API server using Django.
I added admin urls like followings, but whenever I connect to admin page, Django server silently dies with return code 245.
The last console was "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0" and nothing.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/v1/doc/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
```

]

What did I wrong?
I have no AdminModels in admin.py.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to share my experience solving the same issue.

I used python v3.7 and got this issue. Solved this problem by upgrading to **python v3.8** and creating a new venv.

Now my python version FYI:
`Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224279/how-to-resolve-django-admin-error-with-302-problems/61607546#61607546) mentioned this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved this issue exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I used `python:3.7.0-stretch` and switched to `python:3.8.2-buster`. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have/had the exact same issue. Specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.6/3.8/3.9 (tried upgrading, no go)

What did solve it for me, at least ad-hoc, was to use the following admin redirected URL:

```
/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

instead of

```
/admin
```